# This comparison appears to be unintentional because the types '{ loading: Boolean; }' and 'boolean' have no overlap

Tags: reactjs, typescript, state

I am trying to set a loading state for my application with Typescript.

```
const [loading,loadingupdate] = useState<Boolean>(false)
```

```
return ( 
        {
                loading === true ? <></> : <>
                <div className={` ${skin} bigcontainer`}>
                    <div className="main-consign">
                        <h1 className="labelauth">{label}</h1>

                    <Meat label={label} model={model} passworderror={passworderror} emailerror={emailerror} usernameerror={usernameerror} username={usernameupdate} password={passwordupdate} email={emailupdate}/>

                        <button className="submitsign" onClick={()=>{loadingupdate(!loading),submit()}}>Submit</button>

                    <div className="linksign" onClick={()=>{label === authlabels.login ? navigate('/Signup') : navigate('/Login')}}>{label === authlabels.signup ? 'Aready SignedUP?' : 'No account?'}</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </>
        }
    );
```

I wanted my code to show nothing when it equals false. When I press my signup button in the render it will fetch data and when the fetch responds it will change the boolean after it responds so it won't always equal to false.

Like this:

```
async function submit() {
     if (label === authlabels.login) {
         console.log(`This is password: ${password} \n This is username: ${username}`)
     } else {
         console.log(`This is email: ${email} \n This is password: ${password} \n This is username: ${username}`)
            
         const body:any = {
                email: email,
                password: password,
                username: username
            }

         const options: any = optionsMaker(body)

         await fetch('http://localhost:5000/signUp', options).then(response => {
                //console.log(response)// this is response from server, including all ok and error responses 
                if (response.ok)
                    setTimeout(() => {
                        loadingupdate(!loading)
                    },2000)
                else {
                    setTimeout(() => { 
                        console.log(`hi ${loading}`)
                        loadingupdate(!loading)
                    },2000)

                    response.json().then((response)=>{console.log(response)}) 

                }
            })
        }
      }
      
I get an error that my state will always be equal to false but it will change after the fetch typescript is wrong.
```

Comment: The `return ({ loading === true ? <></> : something_else })` will give an error because of the extra `{` and `}`. Should be just `return (loading === true ? <></> : something_else)`.

Comment: this is the answers

Answer (score 2):

Well, you need to declare your state as `boolean` instead (primitive type, with lower case).

Comment: what do i do about this too sir if you want to help?

This condition will always return 'false' since JavaScript compares objects by reference, not value.

Comment: Did you tried changing the type? By looking at the code seems that the type is causing both the issues.

Comment: yes i changed it to this:
 const [loading,loadingupdate] = useState<Boolean>(False)

it is still giving above error but not boolean error

Comment: sorry wrong paste i edited comment

Comment: Well, I meant `useState<boolean>`, the lower case is in the "b".

Comment: oh sorry changed it now to  const [loading,loadingupdate] = useState<boolean>(false) but it still gives error both errors

Answer (score 1):

#### The essence of the problem:

`return ({ loading === true ? <></> : something_else })` will result in an error because of extra `{` and `}`. To fix it, just remove the extra `{` and `}`, so the code is like `return (loading === true ? <></> : something_else)`

#### More explanation of the error message:

Usually, `({...})` is used to create an object, and `({loading})` is ok but `({ loading === true ? value1 : value2 })`  is not ok. Usually, a parser will just give up and throw a `SyntaxError` here.

However, the Typescript Language Server of VSCode does not give up that easily. It still tries to infer the types of variables even if you miss a couple of `(` or `}` (or have some extra).

It probably tried to check this instead: `{ loading } === true`. Since your `loading` was obtained from `useState<Boolean>`, the left side is of type `{ loading: Boolean }`, and the right side is of type `boolean`, hence the error message.